# XLConnect: Error: IllegalArgumentException (Java): Sheet index (-1) is out of range (no sheets)

Tags: r, xlconnect

I am trying to use XLConnect to load in a series of excel workbooks that I have. Using the code:

```
BASZ <- loadWorkbook("BASZ.xlsx", create = TRUE)
```

works every time, and gives me a formal class workbook. However when I go to read in the worksheet I wish to use:

```
data <- readWorksheet("BASZ", sheet = "Sheet1")
```

I always get the same arguement:
"Error: IllegalArgumentException (Java): Sheet index (-1) is out of range (no sheets")

Just yesterday this code worked, im new to this and wondering why this continues to occur. Furthermore; it doesn't matter which excel workbook I try to load, the same error occurs when trying to read in the specific sheet I want to work with. It must be a syntax issue or something im doing wrong right? I fail to understand why it would work, then I close out Studio, then the next day it won't...?

Answer (score 0):

If you have already loaded the excel file using `loadWorkbook()`, you can use the function `readWorksheet()` to read individual sheets. You would only use `readWorksheetFromFile()` if you had not previously loaded the file. So your code should read:

```
BASZ <- loadWorkbook("BASZ.xlsx", create = TRUE)
data <- readWorksheet(BASZ, sheet = "Sheet1")
```

Note that in the second line, the first argument is the variable `BASZ`, not a quoted string.

Comment: I should edit what ive wrote. I miss read what I copied as my code, and had merely attempted to use readworksheetfromfile to remedy my issue. I used "readworksheet(BASZ, sheet = "Sheet1)" as the initial code, however the problem stilled occurred.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so just in case someone else makes the same mistake as me; you have to be working within the directory your xlsx file is in.